# What's the best ruby gem for image uploads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, file-upload, rubygems

I've been dealing with Rails 3, Paperclip and Windows 7 for a few nights now and don't feel like I'm actually getting anywhere. I've hit config issue after config issue and it's a bit of a nightmare. Can anyone recommend any other gems that will accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Would you do the gesture of elaborating the scenario that you are coming across :p I mean show what errors are you facing maybe we all can solve it

Comment: Yes, please come up with your actual problem, and with concrete questions, because paperclip is one of the best image manipulating gem for rails.

Comment: There is some goofy stuff going on in the paperclip.rb file. It adds single quotes around command line arguments. If I can recall, I believe its on line 133 and the line looks like this:

... '#{m}' ...

To get around that problem I just remove the single quotes.

There was also an issue with there being spaces in the ImageMagick path. It didn't like C:\Program Files..., so I had to change it to C:\Progra~1...

That will at least get identify running. I'm also getting errors running  convert. There just seems that I shouldn't have to do all this stuff in order to get Paperclip working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the solution is the change the lib, attachement_fu is outdated and i also think it's not maintained anymore, try to solve the issue with paperclip.

you can visit #rubyonrails or #railsbridge on irc.freenode.net to get some help

Comment: +1 for this one - you probably have problem with configuring imagemagick library and none of the other solutions will help you as all depends on it.

And paperclip is really good solution.

Comment: One problem I'm having is that paperclip.rb is adding single quotes around command line keys, ie '-resize' instead of just -resize. That seems like a problem with the plugin not the imagemagick library. It seems strange that doing that would work fine on a Linux env and not Windows.

Comment: those aren't regular quotes, it's one of the ruby ways to invoke a command line. those are (`) and not ('). not sure what your problem is, you might want to elaborate more on what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Attachment_fu does the same... but you might have better luck posting another question with the problem you are having in Paperclip

Answer (score 0):

You can try two other gem about image manipulation if you really want

- [carrierwave](http://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)
- [dragonfly](http://github.com/markevans/dragonfly)

Answer (score 0):

you can find best gem for upload files and images in below link:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads